Using Make.com to connect to Joomla API is a 404
I'm building a custom Joomla app in make.com.  They do have a Joomla app but it doesn't have all the parameters activated, so I can't push a date into the publish_up field.
I was getting an error with it accepting headers, but I have solved that now using this code:
"headers": {                                          // Default HTTP headers for all modules and RPCs.
    "Authorization": "Bearer {{connection.apiKey}}",   // Authorization by API key, which user will provide in the connection as parameter.
    "Content-Type": "application/vnd.api+json",
    "Accept": "*/*"
},

But now I'm getting a 404 error.  Which can't be an accurate error message because using the default Joomla Make.com module works so the website is definitely accessible and the API key is also working.
What else could cause a 404 error and is there a better way to get an error message that makes sense?

I have found a 404 resource not found can mean the API item you are trying to push to may not be a thing.
